# Determine users county without asking for your location

Tags: javascript, localization

I am trying to determine a users country without asking for there permission.
Example: When I go onto JD.com which is a world wide company it automatically
brings me to JD.ie without asking for a location.

I have already tried the geolocation in JavaScript but I don't need there exact location and it asks for the users permission.

Comment: Web sites do it though the IP address (with the help of a geolocation database). You typically need server-side technologies for that but [there're always ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an API to get their location based on their IP address? Here is one I found http://ip-api.com/.

You will have to retrieve the user's IP in your backend of course.